# The app denies the turn-off button while the app is running in the background

Tags: android

How to programmatically deny or disable the turn-off button or power off while the our app is running in the background?

Thanks

Comment: Hopefully, this is not possible, for obvious security reasons. Malware authors would *love* to prevent people from rebooting their device into safe mode, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't deal with the Power event in any Android Apps. **Events ofPower Buttonare handled in Framework level in Android architecture.** You can't stop framework to dispatch events but accept its dispatch. You can receive the result of event dispatch from framework but not block the process.